# Reading each row in map and combining in reduce to get full matrix in rmr2

Tags: r, hadoop, mapreduce

```
Sys.setenv(HADOOP_CMD="/usr/lib/hadoop/bin/hadoop")
Sys.setenv(HADOOP_STREAMING="/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/hadoop-streaming.jar")

library(rJava)

library(rmr2)
library(rhdfs)

hdfs.init()

data <- hdfs.read.text.file("..../Tab_20.csv") # Tab_20 contains 20 rows and 1000 cols 
s <- strsplit(data, split = ",")
S = as.matrix(s)
output <- matrix(unlist(S), ncol = 1000, byrow = TRUE)
output <- output[2:21,]
class(output) <- "numeric"
ints = 1:nrow(output)
combined_mat = mapreduce(input = ints, map = function(k, v) rowSums(v))
```

I want a matrix to be combined by each row to get a complete matrix. The error I get is as follows:

```
14/11/26 20:10:59 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.reduce.tasks is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.reduces
Required argument: -input <name>
Try -help for more information
Streaming Command Failed!
Error in mr(map = map, reduce = reduce, combine = combine, vectorized.reduce,  : 
  hadoop streaming failed with error code 1
```

The reason I want to read each row separately is to find rowSums in a MapReduce way.

Is there a way to select each row and perform some mathematical operations like computing rowSums of each row and then combining to get a column vector in a map reduce way in rmr2?

What should be written in mapreduce line to read the matrix rowwise for each mapper?